Customizing Legend Text in Smart Chart on Fiori Elements Overview Page
I created an overview page using Fiori Elements in VS Code, and within it, I created a custom card with a Smart Chart. The data is being used from OData. The problem is that when creating a donut-shaped chart, I want to set the text values of the legend displayed on the right according to my preference. Is there any way to do this? I am not using VizFrame.
<Annotation Term="UI.Chart" Qualifier="QUA2">
                    <Record Type="UI.ChartDefinitionType">
                        <PropertyValue Property="ChartType" EnumMember="UI.ChartType/Donut"/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="Title" String="donut"/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="Description" String="donut"/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="Dimensions">
                            <Collection>
                                <PropertyPath>Assetcode</PropertyPath>
                            </Collection>
                        </PropertyValue>
                        <PropertyValue Property="DimensionAttributes">
                            <Collection>
                                <Record Type="UI.ChartDimensionAttributeType">
                                    <PropertyValue Property="Dimension" PropertyPath="Assetcode"/>                                     
                                    <PropertyValue Property="Role" EnumMember="UI.ChartDimensionRoleType/Category"/>         
                                </Record>
                            </Collection>
                        </PropertyValue>
                        <PropertyValue Property="Measures">
                            <Collection>
                                <PropertyPath>BookKamt</PropertyPath>
                            </Collection>
                        </PropertyValue>
                        <PropertyValue Property="MeasureAttributes">
                            <Collection>
                                <Record Type="UI.ChartMeasureAttributeType">
                                    <PropertyValue Property="Measure" PropertyPath="BookKamt"/>
                                    <PropertyValue Property="Role" EnumMember="UI.ChartMeasureRoleType/Axis1"/>
                                </Record>
                            </Collection>
                        </PropertyValue>
                    </Record>

                </Annotation>

I tried to change the text displayed for the dimension 'Assetcode' in the controller, but it's not working well.
 onfilterApply: function (sChannelId, sEventName, aFilters) {
                console.log("donutchart onfilterApply triggered");
                console.log("donutchart aFilters", aFilters);

                var that = this;
                var oSmartChart = that.getView().byId("donutChart");
                
                if (oSmartChart) {
                    oSmartChart.getChartAsync().then(function (oChart) {
                        var oChartBinding = oChart.getBinding("data");

                        if (oChartBinding) {
                            oChartBinding.filter(aFilters); // Apply the filters to the chart binding
                            console.log("donut Filters applied:", oChartBinding.filter(aFilters));
                            oChartBinding.attachDataReceived(function(oDataEvent) {
                                var oData = oDataEvent.getParameter("data");
                                console.log("oData", oData);
                                
                                if (oData && Array.isArray(oData.results)) {

                                    oData.results.forEach(function (item) {
                                        if (item.Assetcode === "BD") {
                                            item.Assetcode = "TEST";
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            item.Assetcode = "AA";
                                        }
                                    });

                                    console.log("oData.results", oData.results);
                                  
                                    oSmartChart.getModel().setProperty("/results", oData.results);
                                    
                                } else {
                                    console.warn("Received data is not an array:", oData);
                                }
                              
                                //  oChartBinding.refresh(true);
                            });
                        } else {
                            console.error("donut Chart binding is still undefined");
                        }
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        console.error("donut Error retrieving chart:", error);
                    });
                } else {
                    console.error("donut Chart is undefined");
                }
                this.formatLegendLabels(); 
            },

            // formatLegendLabels: function(sValue) {
            //     console.log("donut formatLegendLabel TRIGGERED");
            //     console.log("sValue", sValue);
            //     switch (sValue) {
            //         case "BD":
            //             return "TEST"; 
            //         default:
            //             return "AA"; 
            //     }
            // },

